# Ruby code to upload file on web browser

Tags: ruby, upload, automation, cucumber

I am developing an automation script in cucumber with Ruby step definition. I need to upload an excel file from my C Drive to the browser. Could someone help me with the issue?

The HTML Code for the browse button on web page:

```
<input name="ImportFile" type="file" id="ImportFile" size="100" class="f-edit">
```

Comment: What tool are you using to automate the interactions with the browser?

Comment: Cucumber is the test framework. That doesn't do browser interactions. You probably have a library such as watir-webdriver or selenium-webdriver for that, maybe capybara. You should use the proper tags to get attention from the right people. Also, you might investigate if you can use a rest service to upload the file to the server, it would be more simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `watir-webdriver`, you should be able to use the `file_field` method.  For example:

```
b.file_field(:id => "ImportFile").set 'C:\foo.xlsx'
```

But--IMHO--uploading (and downloading) files can be a fickle endeavor.  Dave McNulla's suggestion to use a REST service is a good one and might make the task less painful.  YMMV.